# How do I properly use iloc indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, slice

I have this task:

Create a dictionary and name it cc. The dictionary has two keys: data and target, and the corresponding key values are NumPy arrays. For target, the key value is an array of values from the encoded column satisfaction of df. For data, the key value is an array of sub arrays and each sub array is an observation of one sample across the features in df2.

I am not sure if my code reflects the task, could anyone please take a look?

```
cc = {
"data": df2.iloc[:, :-1].to_numpy(),
"target": df["satisfaction_satisfied"].to_numpy(),
}
```

I am not sure I call the correctly df & df2 and am clueless if my iloc indexing corresponds to what's asked.

Any help will be very much appreciated:)

Thank you!

M.

Answer (score 0):

I tested `pandas` in Python3.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3],
        [2,3,4],
        [3,4,5]]

#       col0 col1 col2
# row 0:  1   2    3
# row 1:  2   3    4
# row 2:  3   4    5

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['row0', 'row1', 'row2'],
                  columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'])


#iloc[rows, cols]
data = df.iloc[:, :-1].to_numpy()
# meaning: All rows and All cols except last col.
print(data)
```

As you can see the code,
the first parameter of iloc is a condition of which rows are indexed, and
the second is a condition of which columns are indexed.

First parameter `:` means "index all rows.
Second parameter `:-1` means "index all columns but last column.
So, iloc finds elements that satisfy conditions.

You want to know about python slicing.  I found good reference:
https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/